# problem publishing a package and installing it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, package

I created a simple package where it only has a `<div> x </div>` and published it with npm publish. Then I tried to install it in a project with npm i and it throws me this error: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled
I tried to install @babel/preset-react, I set the babel.config.js like this

```
module.exports = {
   presets: ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"],
};
```

But I couldn't figure it out.
PS: sorry for my bad english
PS2: i created my app with npx create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really enough info / code in your question to solve your specific problem but my guess would be to check your loaders in `webpack.config.js`.
You should have babel-loader installed and included as a rule in webpack config:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      use: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }
  ]
}
```

Having said that, I found when I wanted to make my own package that starting with create-react-app didn't give enough control and came with a lot of bloat. I'd recommend starting with [createapp.dev](https://createapp.dev/webpack/), where you can select what elements to include in your build and it will generate the boilerplate code. [This example](https://createapp.dev/webpack/react--babel) is probably enough to build a minimal react component package.

[I recently wrote an article](https://medium.com/@arfi720/package-react-components-for-npm-d22cd2f23b8) about my experiences making a simple-as-possible package, it might also help.